# Is there a way to display which grid is activated when re-sizing my browser?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, debugging, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using Bootstrap RC2, and I'm trying to create a responsive page design.  I have a "debug" section at the bottom of my page where I write out to the page various variables and parameters being used.  I'd like to include in that section information on which grid system (xs, sm, md, or lg) is being used when re-sizing my page for testing purposes.  How would I access this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to get this to work with the Bootstrap classes mentioned here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

**example:**

```
<asp:Label ID="SmallGridView" CssClass=".visible-sm" Text="Active Grid: col-sm" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```